# React - useRef is not pausing video

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, react-typescript, use-ref, react-slick

I am using react-slick for slider. I want to stop the video when the slide changes. I use useRef for this, but the play or pause functions do not work. How can i solve this?

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

  const slideAfterChange = (current: number) => {
   console.log("after change", current);
   console.log("video ref", videoRef);
   videoRef.current?.pause();
 };

 const sliderSettings = {
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 3000,
   speed: 1000,
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   afterChange: (currentSlide: number) => slideAfterChange(currentSlide)
 };

 return (
   <div className="App">
      <h1>Slider</h1>
      <Slider {...sliderSettings}>
       <div>
         <video ref={videoRef} controls width="100%" height="100%">
           <source
             src={
               "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
             }
           ></source>
         </video>
       </div>
       <div>
         <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" />
       </div>
     </Slider>
   </div>
 );
}
```

you can see on codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-swirles-m6bw1?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of useRef you can add an id to the video player and then use getElementById.

```js
const slideAfterChange = () => {
    document.getElementById("videoPlayer")?.pause();
};
...
<video id="videoPlayer" controls width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: yeah it worked! But in typescript i wrote 
`const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoPlayer') as HTMLVideoElement;  videoPlayer.pause();`